# How to run multiple Wine instances in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, wine

How can one run multiple wine process at the same time on one machine ?

I'm using a windows software through wine. and I would like to run it in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)
If your wine process can be run from the command line interface such as

```
wine cmd /c @mydoscommand argval1
```

You can run it in parallel with a different argval each time using gnu parallel. For example, the following command:

```
parallel 'wine cmd /c @mydoscommand {}' ::: argval1 argvalB altarg
```

will run these three commands in parallel

```
wine cmd /c @mydoscommand argval1
wine cmd /c @mydoscommand argvalB
wine cmd /c @mydoscommand altarg
```

Be aware, however, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706088/run-wine-in-parallel-with-gnu-parallel-needs-slot-substitution-to-work) SO question, sometimes each running wine process needs to be seperated from each other in which case you need to restrict the parallel wine processes to seperate wineprefix containers as follows for the above example:

```
parallel -j4 'WINEPREFIX=$HOME/slot{%} wine cmd /c @mydoscommand {}' ::: argval1 argvalB altarg
```

Let me break this down for you.

- -j4 limits parallel to 4 parallel processes
- {%} is a place holder for the job slot number
- WINEPREFIX=$HOME/slot{%} causes, for example, process job slot 2 to run in the wine prefix located at /$HOME/slot2 Please note thats not the 2nd *job* its the 2nd job *slot* in however many concurrent processes you allowed with the -j flag.

To find out more about wine prefixes have a look at [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_store_the_virtual_Windows_installation_somewhere_other_than_.7E.2F.wine.3F) and for running 32bit wine commands in 64 bit linux have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix). Finally, to find out more about the poweful gnu parallel options have a look at the [tutorials](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html)

Comment: If your program is not natively capable of running two instances via wine, you should also try using the [AHK run](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command in wine

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late... you can find what you are looking for here : https://www.playonlinux.com/en/. PlayOnLinux allows you to run multiple instances of a windows psoftware, even with different wine configurations. It's magical :)