# run windows program under wine using gnu parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, bioinformatics, wine

I have a very basic script to run multiple copies of a windows population genetics program (msvar.exe) under Wine. It uses "find" to look through multiple folders for an initiation file (INTFILE) and then starts an instance of msvar.exe in each directory using that initiation file. Different folders will have different paramaters in the initiation file so I can run a series of simulations by adding the "&" parameter. Here it is;

```
for i in $(find /home/msvartest -name INTFILE -type f)
do (
cd $(dirname $(realpath $i));
#   wine explorer /desktop=name msvar.exe;
wineconsole --backend=user msvar.exe;
) &
done
```

At the moment I run up to 20 copies of msvar.exe at once each under it's own wineconsole (or wine explorer window) on my dual hexacore machine. Each run instance can take 3 or 4 days, but the program only runs on a single core, so I need to run the simulations in parallel. It looks like Gnu parallel would be a better way to run msvar.exe and would allow me to run more simulations over remote computers. I unsuccessfully tried to get Gnu parallel working with wineconsole following the suggestions in [Run wine in parallel with gnu-parallel - needs {%} slot substitution to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706088). Is anybody able to help, or even better knock up a script I could use.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is very flattering that you accepted my answer, but actually, the answer from @OleTange (who is the author of the brilliant **GNU Parallel**) is the more correct one - see his comment underneath my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't smart enough to get Ole's script working - how embarrassing !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your command is going to get horribly long and unwieldy unless you use an exported function like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
   ...
   ...
}

export -f doit
parallel -j 10 doit ::: {0..99}
```

So, for your example that will look something like (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
   echo Processing $1
   cd $(dirname $(realpath "$1"));
   WINEPREFIX=$HOME/slot{%} wineconsole --backend=user msvar.exe
}
export -f doit

find /home/msvartest -name INTFILE -type f | parallel --dry-run doit
```

Unfortunately I don't have your environment set up to test this but it should be close and easy to correct if there are minor errors. Try and see what it does, then remove the `--dry-run` to let it actually do something.

If you have spaces in your filenames, you should use `-print0` with your `find` command and also add `-0` after `parallel` but that just complicates things for the moment.

Comment: {%} is not replaced in the function - only in the command line.

Comment: Fantastic, that's got me pointed in the right direction and I even understand roughly how they work (I'm a biologist and only know enough about programming to be dangerous!!). Now for the question about using parallel to run msvar.exe on remote servers. If I just add the remote server details between "parallel" and "doit" (following the help file) the remote server says "doit" is not a command, for obvious reasons even to me. How could this be modified to copy a data folder and allow this to be run on a remote server with msvar.,exe installed ?

Comment: YIKES! You are getting to the edges of my abilities too! Maybe get it all working on one server and then ask a new question about how to spread the data and work over additional, remote servers in parallel - and hope Ole is still watching like he always does.

Comment: Yup. Start by posting the script that works on a single machine, and let us take it from there.

Comment: Apologies, Fantastic meant it worked!! All I had to do was modify the directory to the one in use, remove the --dry-run and it worked straight awayit worked straight away. This worksdoit() {
   echo Processing $1
#   cd $(dirname $(realpath "$1"));
cd $(dirname $(readlink -f "$1"));
   WINEPREFIX=$HOME/slot{%} wine /home/DaveB/msvar/msvar0.4.1b/msvar.exe
}
export -f doit

find /home/DaveB/msvar/MSVAR_ORC_NEWUPLOAD -name INTFILE -type f | parallel doit

Comment: Please ignore the script above, it was accidentally inserted. The script that works is exactly as Mark suggested with the directories adjusted for the find command. When I run it I get 20 threads running 20 instances of msvar.exe - awesome. In 4 days I'll get the results. I couldn't get Ole's script working but didn't try to hard. This will help a lot of us and save weeks or months of analysis time. Thanks so much for your efforts. I'll ask about remote execution in another question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
   echo Processing $1
   cd $(dirname $(realpath "$1"));
   WINEPREFIX=$HOME/slot$2 wineconsole --backend=user msvar.exe
}
export -f doit

find /home/msvartest -name INTFILE -type f | parallel doit {} {%}
```

Comment: Yep, you are right - as usual. That looks better ;-)